# react native vertival flatlist not scrolling down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

im trying to scroll vertically on my screen but the flat list is not scrolling down se the code below
[the home page in which the flatlist is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONzZb.png)

```
render(){
    let {container}=styles
    let {dataSource, isloading}=this.state
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View >
        <FlatList
         data={dataSource}
         renderItem={this._renderItem}
         keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
         onEndReached={this._handleLoadMore}
         onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        />
           
       
    </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

}enter code here